# C# webform Redirect is losing Session object

Tags: web-services, session, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I'm running into a problem where I'm losing my Session object after a Redirect but only if I've made a call to an external web service.

Let me clarify:

1. 1st page has session object.
2. 1st page makes call to external web service.
3. After web service call 1st page still has session object.
4. 1st page redirects to 2nd page.
5. 2nd page has no session object.

If I comment out the call to the external web service (#2 above), when I get to #5 there IS a session object.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to have a session object after all 5 steps above?

Comment: How are you making the service call?

Comment: It's a SOAP web service provided by a 3rd party. I create an instance of an object, set a bunch of property values and pass the object (as XML) as a parameter to one of their methods.